# Ionic build process is not terminated

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the following setup:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (/somewhere/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v7.10.0
    npm        : 4.2.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

and when I run the `ionic cordova build ios` everything seems that is working correctly but when I get to the following step:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

Non-system Ruby in use. This may cause packaging to fail.
If you use RVM, please run `rvm use system`.
If you use chruby, please run `chruby system`.

2018-01-01 15:34:41.222 xcodebuild[58463:1614383] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/97/rx420_wx1m3c9ww7fzc4jldm0000gn/T/myapp_2018-01-01_15-34-41.220.xcdistributionlogs'.
Exported myapp.xcarchive to: /somewhere/platforms/ios/build/device
** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **
```

It stops the process, what I mean is that nothing else happens so what I do is just force quit (`ctrl + c`) but this doesn't seems to be ok. If I open the xcodeworkspace everything is generated correctly so the only problem that I have is that the process just prints `** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **` and nothing else happens, have been watching videos on youtube and when they run the command the `** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **` closes the process and you are sent back to the terminal.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

It's worth mentioning that I have added and removed the ios platform multiple times without any variation.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you don't have ruby installed or it can't find it

Comment: I have setup the Ruby platform that is going to be used in the system and the problem is still occurring.

Comment: In case someone has the same problem, just noticed that after a few minutes after running `ionic cordova build ios` it ends after 3 minutes.

Comment: It might be related to this question: [ionic cordova run ios - Export failed with code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462451/ionic-cordova-run-ios-export-failed-with-code-65/53480590#53480590)