# ionic cordova run ios - Export failed with code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm done with research on this error. I get following error when trying to run `ionic cordova run ios --livereload`:

```
[cordova]  Non-system Ruby in use. This may cause packaging to fail.
[cordova]  If you use RVM, please run `rvm use system`.
[cordova]  If you use chruby, please run `chruby system`.
[cordova]  error: archive not found at path '/Users/yassinezeriouh/Desktop/doday2/platforms/ios/DoDay.xcarchive'
[cordova]  ** EXPORT FAILED **
[cordova]  
[cordova]  CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,DoDay.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/yassinezeriouh/Desktop/doday2/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/yassinezeriouh/Desktop/doday2/platforms/ios/build/device,-allowProvisioningUpdates'
```

- re-installed ios
- downgraded ios
- all signing is correct in xcode
- tried with custom build.json
- re-installed all plugins

Running the project in xcode on my device works perfectly, tried to fix this issue since 4 hours, hope you can help.
I'm running iOS 12, using Xcode 10.1, cordova 8.1.2, ionic 4.40 (project is actually running on ionic v3 and was created last month)

My config.xml (except android & ios splash/icon section):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.zeriouh.censored" version="1.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Censored</name>
    <description>Censored</description>
    <author email="cen@so.red" href="http://ce.nsor.ed/">Yassine Zeriouh</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="100" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.2.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inapppurchase" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="com.omarben.inappreview" spec="~0.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="~0.22.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="~0.8.15" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="~0.9.0-beta.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.8.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-apprate" spec="~1.4.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your `config.xml` file.

Comment: Try `cordova clean` and then `ionic cordova run ios --l` commands on your terminal.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda added my config.xml, cordova clean didn't change anything, same error as before.

Comment: Try changing `<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />` to `<engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />` and adding ios platform again

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda didn't change anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this beacuse the xcode 10.1 build in a diferent way to the ionic 3 now

`ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --livereload`

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with `"cordova-ios": "4.5.5"`.
Try following below steps.

- `ionic cordova platform rm ios`
- `npm uninstall cordova-ios`
- `npm install cordova-ios@4.4.0`
- `ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0`
- `ionic cordova run ios --livereload`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after changing my cordova-ios version from 4.5.5 to 4.4.0.

1. in `package.json` I changed `"cordova-ios": "4.5.5"` to `"cordova-ios": "4.4.0"`
2. in config.xml I changed `<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />` to  `<engine name="ios" spec="4.4.0" />`
3. `rm -rf node_modules/ platforms/ios/`
4. `npm i`
5. `ionic cordova build ios`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I'm building for ios with "prod" tag.

I have:

- MacOS catalina 10.5.4
- Xcode version 12.2
- cordova-ios 6.0.0

For me the solution that worked was first sign the app on xcode after the first build issue (open platform/ios with xcode and sign the app). Then I build with the commands that people suggest here, but I have to add the "--device" tag also. After that work good :)

```
ionic cordova run ios --prod --release --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"  --device
```